# Why isn't my solution to Project Euler 9 working?

Tags: python

Problem 9:

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which, 
>   
> `a2 + b2 = c2`
>
> For example, 3<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5<sup>2</sup>.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which `a + b + c = 1000`. Find the product abc.

My approach was to generate triplets and then check if they meet the sum `a + b + c = d`. For that I appliead Dickson's method for generating Pythagorean triplets (Dickson method as explained at Wikipedia: To find integer solutions to `x2 + y2 = z2`, find positive integers `r`, `s`, and `t` : `r2 = 2 * s * t` is a square. Then: `x = r + s;` `y = r + t` and `z = r + s + t`. From this we see that `r` is any even integer and that `s` and `t` are factors of `r2 / 2`.

```
def problem9(d=12):
  def dickson(r=6):
    factors, triplets, st = [], [], (r**2)/2
    for i in range(1, int( sqrt(st)+1 )): # Sqrt optimization
      if st % i == 0:
        factors += [[r, i, st//i]]
    for i in range(len(factors)):
      r,s,t = factors[i][0], factors[i][1], factors[i][2]
      triplets += [[r+s,r+t,r+s+t]]
    return triplets

  def tripletSumsMyDValue(triplets):
    for tri in triplets:
      a,b,c = tri[0],tri[1],tri[2]
      if d == int(a + b + c):
        return tri
      else:
        return None

  inc = 2
  while True:
    found = tripletSumsMyDValue(dickson(inc))
    if found: return found
    else: print(inc,found,'is not!')
    inc += 1
```

It's frustrating thinking you're a genius and few seconds after executing your code you realize that you're caught in an infinite loop :P

The `while True:` loop, it's supposed to stop after hitting the right answer `(200, 375, 425)` but it turns out to be infinite.

The most upsetting is that next code works fine, so please don't point that out. I just want to know what's wrong in mine.

```
def problem9b(d = 12):
  inc = 1
  while True:
    for a in range(1, 100 * inc):
      for b in range(1, 100 * inc):
          c = (a ** 2 + b ** 2) ** .5
          if a + b + c == 1000:
              return a, b, c
    inc += 1
```

Comment: You have all kinds of loops here; which is an infinite one?

Comment: If it helps, I don't know too many geniuses who'd never gotten caught in an infinite loop. (Some of them even got caught working on Infinite Loop for a while…)

Comment: Anyway, if you're going to give us a big code dump, please give us a complete, running example. Better still if you can strip our irrelevant code while still demonstrating your problem (and, as Scott Hunter says, tell us exactly where it goes wrong). See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a *much* easier way to do this;

If instead of diving straight into the coding of it, you look at the maths, you can simplify the problem significantly.

We have two equations;

`a2 + b2 = c2`

`a + b + c = 1000`

So substitute one into the other:

`a2 + b2 = (1000 - a - b)2`

`0 = 10002 - 2000a - 2000b - 2ab`

We also know that `a`, `b`, and `c` are all `<1000`. So, we can get a list of all combinations of `a` and `b` which satisfy that equation, and then simply check what `sqrt(a**2 + b**2)` is.

You can do it in a single (admittedly ugly and not very pythonic) list comprehension, and it takes only a second.

```
[[a,b, sqrt(a**2 + b**2)] for a,b in combinations(range(1,1000),2) if 1000000-2000*a-2000*b+2*a*b==0]
```

[[200, 375, 425.0]]

A `list comprehension` is a quick way of creating a list in python. Any list you create through list comprehension can always be created in a clearer way using loops. You can read about them more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Here's a simple one:

```
a = [i for i in range(10)]
```

which just does the same as:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
  a.append(i)
```

Here's the example i gave;

```
[[a,b, sqrt(a**2 + b**2)] for a,b in combinations(range(1,1000),2) if 1000000-2000*a-2000*b+2*a*b==0]
```

which can be written:

```
triplets = []
for a,b in combinations(range(1,1000),2):
  if 1000000-2000*a-2000*b+2*a*b==0:
    triplets.append([a, b, sqrt(a**2 + b**2)])
```

[`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is just a function of the `itertools` module, you can read about it there.

As is pointed out in the comments below though, there is a way it can be simplified even further;

`0 = 10002 - 2000a - 2000b - 2ab`

can be rewritten to give `b` in terms of `a`.

`a = 1000 * 500-b / 1000-a`

`combinations(range(1,1000), 2)` will give a list a million entries long. It scales with `n2`. By writing `b` in terms of `a`, and only iterating over `range(1,1000)` once, you cut it down to O(n), from O(`n2`).

Instead, you can do:

```
from math import sqrt, floor

for a in range(1, 500):
  b = 1000 * (500-a) / (1000-a)
  c = sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
  if int(floor(c)) == c and 0 < a < b < c:
    print a, b, c
```

You can cast `c` to an `int` if you want, but then if it somehow doesn't work, that would mask it.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining in a more detailed way that list comprehension? It's the first time I read about combinations()

Comment: @will, you can take the analysis a bit further. Your last equation gives: b = 1000 * (500 - a)/(1000 - a), and a < 1000. So all you need to do is iterate and find "a" such that "b" is an integer.

Comment: @linus I didn't even bother to sit down and check if I needed to, as the answer popped out of the terminal so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

```
  def tripletSumsMyDValue(triplets):
    for tri in triplets:
      a,b,c = tri[0],tri[1],tri[2]
      if d == int(a + b + c):
        return tri
      else:
        return None
```

For each triplet in the group, if it's the answer, you return it; if it isn't, you return `None`. That means you never look at any triplet after the first in each group. The answer appears in group 150, which has triplets that add up to `22952, 11704, 7956, 4960, 4212, 2968, 2720, 1980, 1736, 1400, 1260, 1040, 1000, 900, 880`; since the `22952` is not `1000`, you fail that group.

The easiest way to fix that is to just remove the whole `else` clause. If you never `return tri` during the loop, you'll fall off the end of the function and return `None` by default.

However, it's worth noting that, even with this fix, your code will never terminate for a number that has no answers, even though you I'm pretty sure you quickly reach a point where no further values could possibly work. (Without reading it carefully I'm not sure where that point is; maybe `inc > d`?)

---

As a side note, you could simplify this code a lot. First, if `tri` always has three members (which it does), the following are equivalent:

```
a,b,c = tri[0],tri[1], tri[2]
a,b,c = tri
```

Or you can even do `for a,b,c in triplets:`. Or, even simpler:

```
for tri in triplets:
    if d == int(sum(tri)):
        return tri
```

Answer (score 1):

Since c = 1000 - a - b, this shorter and faster Python code can also be followed:

```
# i = a, k = b, j = c
for i in range (1 , 1000):
for k in range (i + 1 , 1000):
    j = 1000 - i - k
    if (i ** 2 + k ** 2 == j ** 2) & (i + j + k == 1000):
        print (i * k * j)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have written the program in a simple way as follows:

```
#function to find the pythagorean triplet
#Using Dickson formula
def pythagorean_triplet_dickson():
 for r in range(1,1000):
  for s in range(1,r):
   if ((r**2)/2)%s == 0:
    t = (r**2/2)/s
    if r+s+r+t+r+t+s == 1000:
     return (r+s)*(r+t)*(r+t+s)

#Printing the result
print pythagorean_triplet_dickson()
```

You can also use [m, n formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/pythagorean-triples.html) which has better execution time compared to Dickson method. Check out the source to see that program also :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
start = time.time()
def isok():
    for a in range(100,1000):
        for b in range(100,1000):
            for c in range(100,1000):
                if a + b + c == 1000 and a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c **2:
                    print("a is {} b is {} c is {}".format(a,b,c))
                    print("anwser is",a * b * c)
                    return True
print(isok())
elapsed = (time.time() - start)
print("This code took: " + str(elapsed) + " seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,500):
    for j in range(1,500):
        c = (i ** 2 + j ** 2) ** 0.5
        if i+j+c ==1000:
            print(i*j*c)`
```

I guess this is the shortest code. I use 500 because hypotenuse must be bigger than other edges, and simple math :D

Comment: Why 500? We can imagine `a=300` `b=310` and `c=390`